# Remove Duende IdentityServer from MS Blazor Web Assembly template solution server project

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I just created a Blazor Web Assembly solution for .net 6 with 'Individual Accounts' and 'ASP.NET Core Hosted' selected.

This message is displayed in a ReadMe.txt in the .Server project:

> This code includes a dependency on Duende IdentityServer. This is an
> open source product with a reciprocal license agreement. If you plan
> to use Duende IdentityServer in production this may require a license
> fee. To see how to use Azure Active Directory for your identity please
> see https://aka.ms/aspnetidentityserver To see if you require a
> commercial license for Duende IdentityServer please see
> https://aka.ms/identityserverlicense

So looks like Microsoft is using commercial very expensive software for its Blazor WA TEMPLATE Server element.

Firstly, it's ridiculous to include commercial software in their Blazor template - I can only assume they started using it before the switch to 'Duende' and it no longer being free.

Yearly fees of $1000s (depending on the project) is not acceptable for most projects just for identity.

I can see this package in the .Server project:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer

If I remove this I presume that I've removed all traces of the Duende commercial software from the project?

Also, is there any way to template out a Blazor Web Assembly project with Server element (for Authentication etc) that doesn't use commercial software (or Microsoft Identity Platform).

Using .net Core Identity for authentication on the server would be fine for example - but I guess this doesn't exist as a template?

Thanks.

Comment: It is still relatively fresh new, that Duende is no more free to everyone, so MS is is still using it inside of the template. You can use older version without any restrictions, or you can ask for community licence. More info here: https://duendesoftware.com/specialoffers

Comment: [ASP.NET Core 6 and Authentication Servers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-6-and-authentication-servers/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor without Duende Identity Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74990506/blazor-without-duende-identity-server)

Comment: This applies to .net 7 and earlier. Duende is phased out in .net 8