# Blazor without Duende Identity Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

I have a small Blazor WASM project that I recently migrated to .net 6. But now I tried to run the published project and the application warned me that I don't have a license for Duende Identity Server.

My question is:

Can I do without the Duende Identity Server?

In my application, I need user login and role assignment. I want to have users defined only for this application and I want to use the application database to store them.

My Program.cs looks like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultOutboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

var appDbConStr = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDbConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(appDbConStr));

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, AppDbContext>(opt => 
    {
        opt.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add(UserClaim.Role);
        opt.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add(UserClaim.Role);

        opt.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add(UserClaim.Avatar);
        opt.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add(UserClaim.Avatar);

        opt.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add(UserClaim.Nick);
        opt.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add(UserClaim.Nick);
    });

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IRazorRendererHelper, RazorRendererHelper>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<Vks.Server.Services.SerialGenerator>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Thank you

Comment: Isn't it called "Duende" instead of "Dude"?

Comment: Duende is a paid-for library and service (super expensive too). You can use it for free on local development but if you wish to use it for production use you will need a license.

Are you using their Identity Server? or just the BFF library?

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected the identity server name.
Sorry, but I don't know if Identity Server or BFF library is used. I used a template from Visual Studio, since I'm pretty new to Blazor. Is it possible to find out from the attached Program.cs?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do what you want without Duende. You'll need to find another identity provider, or create your own. Stack Overflow isn't here to find an alternative provider for you. We also won't create an identity provider for you, but if you do try to implement one and run into specific issues along the way, it's possible to make a valid question for those issues.

Comment: Use default ASP.NET CORE Identity (do not add reference to Duende)
Must read articale covers all features of ASP.NET CORE Identity 
https://chsakell.com/2018/04/28/asp-net-core-identity-series-getting-started/

Answer (score 4):

Use default ASP.NET CORE Identity (do not add reference to Duende).
Must read article covers all features of ASP.NET CORE Identity
https://chsakell.com/2018/04/28/asp-net-core-identity-series-getting-started/

Remove Duende reference by deleting reference on Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer (duende is sub referenced)

Add asp.net core identity as follow:

```
    builder.Services
    .AddIdentity<ApplicationUser<int>, ApplicationRole>(config => 
    { 
        config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
        config.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;       
        config.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
        config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        config.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        //...other opts//
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddUserManager<CustomUserManager>() // inherited from UserManager with overriden logic
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddTokenProvider<CustomAuthenticatorTokenProvider>(TokenOptions.DefaultAuthenticatorProvider) // inherited from AuthenticatorTokenProvider with overriden logic
    .AddPasswordValidator<CustomPasswordValidator>(); // implements IPasswordValidator for additional password validation
```

Comment: Thank you. The article looks promising. I'm going to see him.

Comment: This whole solution is a total cluster ****. Adding a requirement for Angular? Non-starter. Microsoft needs to fix this default blazor tax.